# Forcing Aggressive JIT

Tags: c#, .net, jit

As .net matures, the JIT capabilities have been improved to be brilliantly lazy.  That is, don't produce machine code if it isn't needed. In general, this is a good thing.

However, if I am trying to [warmup an application](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series) I may prefer an aggressive JIT stance.  Is there a way to configure a .net application so that all methods of a class are JIT compiled, simply because -the class was constructed?

If yes, my favorite object-creational pattern could instantiate my appliation's object-graph, and I would have everything JIT-ready simultaneously.  That would be nice.

Can this be done?

Comment: You can look at .NET Native. Afaik, right now it's only for Windows Store apps but they're going to expand to other types later. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You could use ngen or it could be done manually my calling `RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod` per method.

Comment: Isn't `generating machine code [when needed] at runtime` a fundamental part of a JIT compiler? There's always the [Native Image Generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx), but of course there's the [trade-offs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2007/09/15/to-ngen-or-not-to-ngen.aspx) between the two.

Comment: Ngen.exe is the obvious approach, the multicore JIT feature of .NET 4.5 does it too.

Answer (score 2):

As a side note - you could use [NGen.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf(v=vs.110).aspx) to produce native image of your dll's at deployment time (NB:It's not a perfect solution - as it has some drawbacks - check out the documentation carefully)

Answer (score 0):

you mean, you want everything ahead-of-time compiled :-)

They finally did this for you - [announced at Build 2014](http://techcrunch.com/2014/04/02/microsoft-updates-visual-studio-with-support-for-universal-projects-typescript-1-0-and-net-native-code-compilation/):

> Somasegar told me that developers told Microsoft that .NET was always
>   a very productive language to program in, but it didn’t always deliver
>   the performance they were looking for. “We’ve been working on a lot of
>   innovation to show developers that .NET is still a very viable
>   platform for developers who want to build apps in this modern world,”
>   he said. With the .NET native ahead-of-time compiler, developers will
>   see faster startup times, lower memory usage and overall better
>   performance, Microsoft promises. This new feature is currently in
>   preview and allows developers to target both the X64 and ARM
>   platforms.

You can [try it out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/dotnetnative.aspx) (preview only at the moment, and possibly only working for 'universal' apps so YMMV as to how useful it is), more info is [available on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn584397.aspx)